# Get product variation attribute titles - WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, taxonomy, customization

Hi there so when I am on a product page and I loop through the variations, I want to list their attributes WITH their titles.

I have my code at a point which lists the variations attribute values but cannot get titles to appear. Here is a screenshot of what I have, the 500/238/530 are the attribute VALUES.
[image]

Here is my current code:

```
foreach ($variations as $key => $value) {
            ?>
            <form action="<?php echo esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ); ?>"method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" value="<?php echo $value['variation_id']?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $post->ID ); ?>" />
                <?php
                if(!empty($value['attributes'])){
                    foreach ($value['attributes'] as $attr_key => $attr_value) {
                    ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $attr_key?>" value="<?php echo $attr_value?>">
                    <?php
                    }
                }
                ?>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <b><?php echo implode('/', $value['attributes']);?></b>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $value['price_html'];?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo apply_filters('single_add_to_cart_text', __( 'Add to cart', 'woocommerce' ), $product->product_type); ?></button>
                                <a href="#" class="add-request-quote-button button" data-product_id="<?php echo $value['variation_id']?>" data-wp_nonce="8b92ff6dd4">Add to quote</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
            <?php
            }
```

How can I add in each attributes title? I have tried [this link](http://woocommerce%20variation%20attribute%20titles%20from%20name) which resulted int eh NULLs you can see in my image.

Thanks